# Labeling reference sample size for iNEXT and ggiNEXT type 1 plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, inext

I want to label the reference sample size for each of my assemblages when creating a sample size based sampling curve with ggiNEXT. This information is stored in: iNEXT_Obj$DataInfo$n.

I am looking for a way to include these labels within the wrapper ggiNEXT using the "label = " argument so I can follow with " + geom_text() that is properly referenced. Example code below.

```
plot1 <-ggiNEXT(iNEXT_Obj, type=1, facet.var="Assemblage", label = iNEXT_Obj$DataInfo$n)

plot1 + facet_wrap(~Assemblage, ncol=4) + geom_text()
```

Error in ggiNEXT(iNEXT_Obj, type=1, facet.var="Assemblage",  :
unused argument (label = iNEXT_Obj$DataInfo$n)

I would like the values for each of the points that have the triangle, circle, and square points on each of the four graphs added below.

[image: Graph example with points of interest]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please read and incorporate elements from [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1082435). Especially the aspects of using `dput()` for the input and then an explicit example of your expected dataset?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.